# How to implement stripe with react-native using expo?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, expo, stripe.js

I have been searching a lot and seen a lot of similar questions but non of them fits in my requirements.

I need to implement Stripe in react-native built using expo XDE. As mentioned in expo docs here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments.html#importing-payments, I will have to detach my project to implement payment but I don't want to do that. Is there any alternative?
Also other wrappers available on GitHub doesn't facilitates projects built with expo completely. I am unable to find any complete wrapper or at least a guide to build my own.

I am looking for a solution for subscription based model, I need to charge my customers recursively and allow them to upgrade/downgrade their packages during an on going paid/trial period. I don't want to hold credit card information and allow customers to update their billing information whenever needed. Implement refund policies as well.

Comment: Stripe just released the official Stripe client library for React Native as public beta: [stripe-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native). I would suggest looking into that.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to eject from Expo, you can use StripeCheckout component from `expo-stripe-checkout` on iOS and Android (though on Android you can still use the Payments module). Here's the link to the repo with further instructions: https://github.com/briansztamfater/expo-stripe-checkout

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced the same issue, this is the conclusion:

Short version: **You'll need to detach if you need payments (Stripe) on iOS.** (*If you don't, juse use the `Payments` module from Expo - it is not obvious right away, but they do state in the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments.html) that it is based on `tipsi-stripe`*).

**Explanation**: The Expo SDK used to contain a **payments** module for both Android & iOS. For the last 3-4 versions of Expo, `Payments` has been removed from the iOS SDK because "Apple sometimes rejects apps which contain the Stripe SDK but don’t offer anything for sale.".

Reference: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments.html

**Solution:** `detach` [to ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html), and then add the `Payments` module manually. I can say from experience this is not a nice or straightforward process, as it first introduced the concept of manually building your app using MacOS/Xcode which is a pain to say the least for a Win user.

If you do not want to detach, it means you will have to implement your own, custom way of communicating with Stripe and not than their official SDK, which will imply [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security) issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We concluded same. Finally decided to detach

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case? Having to detach is a complete dealbreaker as it negates all the convenience of using Expo in the first place.

Comment: Well, in the latest Expo version (25.0) it still is the case unfortunately. Expo does a poor job at making sure people understand Expo doesn't have nearly wide enough module coverage for every use case and that they should carefully look up every module before starting a project. Unfortunately did the same mistake as many other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can all Stripe API directly. map Stripe customer Id and your user id in your backend. then you can call [this API's](https://stripe.com/docs/api) from frontend using stripe customer id.

Comment: Yeah but then all sensitive details will be touching our servers and services and we'll have to take care of all securities and PCI compliance issues. No?